# 3D reconstruction in tetrahedra

Tags: graphics, 3d, voronoi, delaunay

2 parallel surfaces with constant height difference ζ are given (with the reference points which are in the 2D plane around the perimeter). On every surface we have boron diagrams and skeletons and delon triangles. What is the methodology to calculate the 3D geometric reconstruction of the object which has the 2 aforementioned surfaces as bottom and top sides? (Hints: the calculated volume is in the form of a tetrahedron, in the construction of tetrahedra we have no overlap)